# how to keep windows $PATH when 'sudo su -' on windows-subsystem-for-linux

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu (version 1804.2018.817.0) from the Window Store on top of Windows 10 (version 1803 build 17134.345) using the Window Subsystem for Linux.

When I first open the console I'm logged in with the account I created when I first ran Ubuntu. In this context I can execute things in the Windows path like `cmd.exe`.

However, when I switch to root using `sudo su -`, the $PATH variable no longer contains the Windows path information. So when I type `cmd.exe` it says `cmd.exe: command not found`.

My questions are:

1. Where do the Window $PATH values come from when I first open Ubuntu?
2. Why doesn't the root user get the Windows $PATH values when I use `sudo su -`?
3. How can I configure bash so that $PATH contains Window path values when I use `sudo su -`, so that I can run commands like `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Open `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss` in regedit > find ``DistributionName"="Ubuntu1804"` > What's the value of `DefaultUid` and `Flags`?

Answer (score 1):

I answer although this topic belongs rather to [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

1. *Where do the Window $PATH values come from when I first open Ubuntu?*. 

   From standard [Windows %PATH% environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) because `ubuntu.exe` process is a child of `conhost.exe` (as well as the Windows command prompt `cmd.exe`).
2. *Why doesn't the root user get the Windows $PATH values when I use `sudo su -`?* 
   Check `sudo sudo -V | grep PATH` from `wsl` prompt. Read `man sudo` for the explanation:

> ```
> ENVIRONMENT
>      sudo utilizes … environment variables.  The security policy 
>      has control over the actual content of the command's environment.
> …
>      PATH             May be overridden by the security policy.
> ```
>
> The default security policy is **sudoers**, which is configured via
>   the file `/etc/sudoers`.

Try this illustrative example (paste following three commands severally into an open `cmd` command prompt):

```
wsl echo ${#PATH}
wsl sudo su   -c 'echo ${PATH} ^&^& echo ${#PATH}'
wsl sudo su - -c 'echo ${PATH} ^&^& echo ${#PATH} ^&^& cat /etc/sudoers ^| grep Default'
```

Result (the latter command takes a look at `/etc/sudoers` as well):

```
d:\test> wsl echo ${#PATH}
1557

d:\test> wsl sudo su   -c 'echo ${PATH} ^&^& echo ${#PATH}'
[sudo] password for user:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
88

d:\test> wsl sudo su - -c 'echo ${PATH} ^&^& echo ${#PATH} ^&^& cat /etc/sudoers ^| grep Default'
[sudo] password for user:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
70
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

Read `man sudoers` as well for further explanation of *Defaults* options:

> ```
> env_reset   If set, sudo will run the command in a minimal environment containing
>             the TERM, PATH, HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER, USERNAME and SUDO_*
>             variables… If the secure_path option is set, its value will be used
>             for the PATH environment variable.  This flag is on by default.
>
> secure_path Path used for every command run from sudo.  If you don't trust the people
>             running sudo to have a sane PATH environment variable you may want to use
>             this.  Another use is if you want to have the “root path” be separate from
>             the “user path”.  Users in the group specified by the exempt_group option
>             are not affected by secure_path.  This option is not set by default.
> ```

3. *How can I configure bash so that $PATH contains Window path values when I use  `sudo su -`, so that I can run commands like `cmd.exe`*?

   - You could use `env_keep` option via `sudoedit` (not recommended for [security reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8581/21471)) to preserve your user's environment variables.
   - For swift advance, copy and paste the following into the `root` prompt. It will add all folder paths from current Windows `%path%` variable to `$PATH`. You might consider make it a `.sh` script and add some advanced logic:

```
cmd.exe /c echo works!            # merely for documentation
echo "${#PATH}"                   # merely for documentation
cmd_path=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C echo "%path:\\\\=\\\\\\\\%"`
OIFS="$IFS"                       # backup $IFS
IFS=';'
read -a c_p_n <<< "${cmd_path}"
IFS="$OIFS"                       # restore $IFS
OPATH="${PATH}"                   # backup  $PATH
for i in "${!c_p_n[@]}"; do PATH=${PATH%/}:$(sed -e 's#^\(.\):#/mnt/\L\1#' -e 's#\\#/#g' <<< "${c_p_n[$i]}"); done
echo "${#PATH}"                   # merely for documentation
cmd.exe /c echo works!            # merely for documentation
```

**Result**:

```
user@COMP:~$ sudo su -
root@COMP:~# cmd.exe /c echo works!            # merely for documentation
cmd.exe: command not found
root@COMP:~# echo "${#PATH}"                   # merely for documentation
70
root@COMP:~# cmd_path=`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C echo "%path:\\\\=\\\\\\\\%"`
root@COMP:~# OIFS="$IFS"                       # backup $IFS
root@COMP:~# IFS=';'
root@COMP:~# read -a c_p_n <<< "${cmd_path}"
root@COMP:~# IFS="$OIFS"                       # restore $IFS
root@COMP:~# OPATH="${PATH}"                   # backup  $PATH
root@COMP:~# for i in "${!c_p_n[@]}"; do PATH=${PATH%/}:$(sed -e 's#^\(.\):#/mnt/\L\1#' -e 's#\\#/#g' <<< "${c_p_n[$i]}"); done
root@COMP:~# echo "${#PATH}"                   # merely for documentation
1555
root@COMP:~# cmd.exe /c echo works!            # merely for documentation
works!
```

Comment: I also suggest reading the man page for `su`. It calls out the `-` argument in `su -`: `- ... start the shell as a login shell .... initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH`. In other words, by `su -`, you are telling it to throw away the environment variables such as PATH of the current user.

Comment: @omajid Compare `wsl sudo su - -c 'echo $PATH ^&^& cat /etc/sudoers ^| grep Defaults'` (note the `-` argument) and `wsl sudo su -c 'echo $PATH ^&^& cat /etc/sudoers ^| grep Defaults'`. Different `$PATH`, different `secure_path`. In any way, Windows `%path%` equivalent is missing thru `env_reset`.